# Google play cnaceled purchase

Tags: google-play, in-app-purchase

I have game in google play with in app purchanses.

My users purchased content but after about 2 weeks thats purchases canceled. I recived a lot of message from my users `Why my purchased canceled?`

I can`t to understand why purchased canceled, any ideas?

[image: Screen canceled operations]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the **Google Play Billing Library** v2.0+ you have to [Acknowledge the Purchase](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_library_overview#acknowledge)
You can do that as soon as the purchase is completed with a status `PurchaseState.PURCHASED` or check for Purchases pending to be acknowledged when the app starts and acknowledged them ASAP. To do that, you just have to implement the code in the link.